# Using Xcode with Javascript/Coffeescript and Titanium?

Tags: javascript, xcode4, titanium, coffeescript

I am getting rather annoyed with Titanium Studio so I decided to look for an alternative. I have used many IDEs (such as Aptana, Komodo, Netbeans, TextMate) but they have never seemed to be so streamlined and efficient as Xcode (especially with its Git integration).

So my question is: **Is there a way to edit Javascript/Coffeescript files while using the full project interface *in Xcode*?** (most importantly *git integration*)

(I'm using Xcode 4 with Mac OSX Lion)

Thanks in advance
Fred

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have not done Coffeescript development, but my answer covers how to use Xcode for languages other than C, C++, and Objective-C. Create either an external build system project or an empty project in Xcode. When you create the project, Xcode gives you the option to create a local git repository for the project. If you already have a git repository, you must add the Xcode project file to the repository.

After creating the project, add your files to the project. Xcode 4 has Javascript syntax coloring. If your Javascript files have the file extension .js, Xcode will automatically give you Javascript syntax coloring. I don't know how different Coffeescript is from Javascript, but you can give your Coffeescript files Javascript syntax coloring by choosing Editor > Syntax Coloring > JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Do the files auto-add themselves when I create them in another editor?

Comment: Creating a file in another editor doesn't automatically add it to the Xcode project. You have to add the files to the project in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question (ie: are you looking for something better than XCode, or just a way to integrate them), but have you looked at [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)?  It has excellent Git integration, one of the best JS editors I've used, and has a plugin for [CoffeeScript](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=4701)

If you just want it integrated with XCode, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use Xcode with git integration, not any other editor. If I can't use Xcode, I'll just use Titanium Studio or Komodo because it is easier than learning a new IDE.